# Next Button Code from the access database by visual express 2010

Tags: vb.net, button

I am making a program about laboratory database and I made next/ previous buttons the program is working fine when I click next/previous button and when the row is number one but when I choose items from combo-box it is not WORKING start again from row number 2 in access database but I want complete after that search

here video link explain the problem

http://www.gulfup.com/?A2Xg8h

```
Private Sub btnn_Click(ByVal sender As System ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnn.Click
       If txtid.Text = 500008 Then
           MsgBox("أنت الآن في السجل الأخير ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "تنبيه")
       End If
       Me.BindingContext(LDS, "lab").Position = Me.BindingContext(LDS, "lab").Position + 1
   End Sub
   Private Sub btnp_Click(ByVal sender As System, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnp.Click
       If txtid.Text = 101001 Then
         MsgBox("أنت الآن في السجل الأول ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "تنبيه")
       End If
       Me.BindingContext(LDS, "lab").Position = Me.BindingContext(LDS, "lab").Position - 1
   End Sub
```